# Сменить оформление в зависимости от времени

Tags: javascript

друзья и коллеги!) 
Как работать с объектом Date() JS? Нужно менять оформление сайта в разное время суток

```
var d = new Date();
if(d.toLocaleTimeString()>'00:00'){
    var el = document.getElementById('elTime');
    el.className = 'elem elemDark';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кажется, вам нужно это, просто под if добавьте нужный код

```js
if(new Date().getHours() > 12 && new Date().getHours() < 19)
  alert("День");// нужный вам код
else
  alert("Ночь");
```